# How to print output of affected rows with Powershell and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I'm having a little problem on how to execute two queries one after the other.

In my Powershell script I'm adding records in a loop (which works perfectly fine). Outside the LOOP I execute a query to Delete "x" number of records based on the TIMESTAMP (which is working) but after that one is executed I want to run a query to display the number of ROWS that have been affected and display it. Below is my code.

Thanks in advance!

```
### ============================================================= 
       ### Deleting every record that is 30 minutes old
       ### =============================================================  

        $command = $connection.CreateCommand();
        $command.Connection  = $connection;
        $command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM workstation_userlogged
                                WHERE lastupdate < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)";


        $records_deleted = "SELECT row_count()"; #count number of rows affected by the delete query

        $command.CommandText = "$records_deleted";

         TRY{
            $command.ExecuteNonQuery() | out-null;
            Write-Host "Successfully deleted $records_deleted records from the Database" -ForegroundColor Green;
        }
        CATCH{
            Write-Host "Caught the exception" -ForegroundColor Red;
            Write-Host "$_" -ForegroundColor Red;
        }
```

Comment: $command.ExecuteNonQuery() should return the number of affected rows. '[Int]$rows = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()'

Comment: @paul it does not work, it returns 0. you're telling me to assign [int]$rows to command.executenonquery() when it is being used by 2 queries.

Comment: Does it work if You  only execute 1 query? I don't have a db available for testing

Comment: well my delete query does work.. but it does make sense not to assign $row to a command.executenonquery when it is being used for both queries.

Comment: well in the case that it works with your delete query doesnt that make the second query unnecessary and thus solves the problem? If not then why not just run a select `COUNT()` with your where condition before deleting the rows?

Comment: no because I want to show how many were affected AFTER the delete query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ExecuteNonQuery` if you want the result set returned for you (which you do.. that's why you're running `SELECT row_count()`).  Try the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead.